# Hibernate PersistentList and ArrayList

Tags: java, hibernate, collections, arraylist

Dear All,
I have a problem with an `ArrayList` annotated with `@ElementCollection`.

I need it to be an `ArrayList`, and when Hibernate load the object from the session, it is a hibernate Persistent List.

How can I solve the issue? I am using Hibernate with hibernate annotations, no JPA, so I can't do any `@PostLoad`

Best Regards

Comment: by the way, `@ElementCollection` is a JPA annotation ;)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use a `List` instead of `ArrayList`:

```
@ElementCollection(..)
private List elements;
```

If you then want to do something with an `ArrayList` specifically, you can create a copy:

```
ArrayList list = new ArrayList(elements);
```

You need to use interfaces, because ORMs use custom implementations of these interfaces to achieve orm-specific functionality, e.g. lazy loading. Hibernate doesn't have a specific subclass of `ArrayList`, it has a `PersistentList`, which is justa `List`.

Comment: depends on what "complex" means

Comment: Is there an alternative for XML configuration?